# Parse RSS from URLs gives me "Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence"

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, rss

I'm trying to manipulate RSS contents and transform it into JSON objects using Java. The sources that I'm using are:

http://rss.uol.com.br/feed/economia.xml
and
http://g1.globo.com/dynamo/pr/parana/rss2.xml

First, I tried something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = b.parse(myUrl);
//working with doc variable...
```

The second url works OK (I think because it has `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on top of it). But the second one failed in

> Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence

So, I tried to do something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myUrl.getBytes());
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
InputSource io = new InputSource(reader);

io.setEncoding("UTF-8");
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(io);
//working with doc variable...
```

But now the second url is giving me this error:

> Content is not allowed in prolog

While the first one still giving me the same old error.

How can I read RSS files from it's URL without get any charset error?

Comment: In your second code you're trying to give the URL as if it's the actual data. It's not.

Comment: Basically, that first URL provides invalid XML - line 5, the Ú isn't correctly encoded.

Comment: I know that, but I can't change the XML because it's a external file.

Comment: I suggest you tell the source of the invalid file then. If they fix it, everyone benefits.

Comment: It's one of the biggest website in Brazil. I think I'm too small for then...

Comment: The bigger they are, the more important it is that they serve valid data. I would hope they'd be embarrassed at serving broken files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (JavaSE 8)

```
String uri="http://rss.uol.com.br/feed/economia.xml";   
URL myUrl=new URL(uri);

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

//If you do not need a proxy:
//InputStream is=myUrl.openStream();

//I needed a proxy: 
java.net.Proxy pxy =new java.net.Proxy( java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP,new java.net.InetSocketAddress("apoderado-externo",8080));
URLConnection urlConn=myUrl.openConnection(pxy);
urlConn.connect();
InputStream is =urlConn.getInputStream();


//Prepare to parse the stuff 
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
InputSource io = new InputSource(reader);

io.setEncoding("UTF-8");
Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(io);
//working with doc variable...
```

I think not only the xml does not provide the encoding but also the HTTP header 'Content-type' seems not to be present. Maybe BOM is not present either ....